# How do I create a truly multi-purpose endpoint using WebAPI 2 with optional parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Thanks for looking.

I am attempting to make the following code work:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
[AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("{email}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string email = null)
    {        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return Json(someUserProfileObject);
        }
        
        return Json(someListOfUserProfiles);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try and access /api/user/some@email.com, I get a `405`.

## SOLVED!

Please see solution in my answer below.

Comment: Congratulations on solving your issue.  Please keep the Q&A format by posting a solution rather than editing the question.

Comment: You bet--I will revise.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to finish composing this question when I stumbled on the answer.  Basically, special characters [don't work well in URL Request Paths](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx).  I used a query string instead and revised my code to this:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/user")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
    [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string email = null)
        {        
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
                return Json(someUserProfileObject);
            }
            
            return Json(someListOfUserProfiles);
        }
    }
```

Now all works fine and I can use the endpoint to get both lists of users as well as just an individual user if the querystring is provided.

Cheers!